# How to invoke arrow function having parameters in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, formik

Being new to reactJs, struggling to understand how to invoke arrow function having parameters.

I have defined this function in file1.js

```
const fetchSavedFilters = ({ tenantId, id }) => {
    client.query({
      query: GET_SAVED_FILTER,
      variables: { tenantId: tenantId, id: id, },
      fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    }).then(
      resp => {
        console.log("Responce received for single savedFilter :", resp);
        return resp;
      }
    );
  };
```

I have a form in file2.js where user user will click on submit button and onSubmit handler is defined in file1.js.

submit button code from file2.js

```
<Col md={2}>
                    <Button type="submit" 
                    color="primary" 
                    disabled={loading}>
                      {intl.formatMessage({ id: "button.filter" })}
                    </Button>
                </Col>
```

handler from file1.js

```
<Formik
                    onSubmit={(values) => {
                      if(values.savedFilterIds.length > 0){
                        var fetchedFilters = fetchSavedFilters(tenantId, values.savedFilterIds[0]);
                        refetch({
                          search: initialValues,
                        });
                      }else{
                        refetch({
                          search: values,
                        });
                      }
                    }}
```

fetchSavedFilters(tenantId, id) is getting invoked but the parameters are undefined which is stopping me from trying to fetch the record from dynamoDB. I dont understand how to fix this.

Comment: Write `const fetchSavedFilters = (tenantId, id) =>` , not `const fetchSavedFilters = ({ tenantId, id }) =>`

Comment: Thanks Ajeeth, it was a simple one I could have noticed on my own. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined your function in a destructuring fashion.

```js
const fetchSavedFilters = ({ tenantId, id }) => {
  //...
}
```

The above means that you are expecting a single object as a parameter, with properties `tenantId` and another properties `id` inside the object.

Now when you invoke the above function, you will need to invoke with an object with the two aforementioned properties. You have 2 options to invoke the function,

- option A

```js
const parameter = { tenantId: 123, id: 456 };
fetchSavedFilters(parameter);
```

- option B

```js
fetchSavedFilters({ tenantId: 123, id: 456 });
```

Alternatively, update your function declaration to none destructuring fashion.

```js
const fetchSavedFilters = (tenant, id) => {
  //...
}
```

Notice the curly braces has been removed. Now this function is expecting 2 parameters, first parameter named `tenant` while another parameter named `id`, which you can then invoke the function by passing in two parameters

Comment: This is the explanation to what Ajeeth has simply commented to my question, but thanks for the detailed answer, I ll remember and practice.